# Как работает нормализация Java (normalize)

Tags: java

Есть такой код, который создает дерево DOM из файла `FILE_NAME`, а метод `writeFileXML()` записывает изменения в файл:

```
public class Class1 
{
    public Document doc;

    public void initFileXML()
    {
        DocumentBuilder docbuilder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
        doc = docbuilder.parse(FILE_NAME); 
        doc.normalize();

    } 


    public void writeFileXML()
    {
        Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
        transformer.setOutputProperty(javax.xml.transform.OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
        DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
        FileOutputStream file = new FileOutputStream(FILE_NAME);
        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(file);
        transformer.transform(source, result); 
    } 


    public void readXML()
    {
        int i = 0;

        NodeList nodelist = doc.getElementsByTagName("taskParent");

        do
        {
            Node node = nodelist.item(i); 
            //и выводим в консоль
            System.out.println(node.getTextContent());

        }while(++i < nodelist.getLength());  
    }



    //И еще много разных методов
    ...
    ...
}
```

и есть такой xml-файл:

```
<taskParent>
    <taskChild1>Текст1</taskChild1>
    <taskChild2>Текст2</taskChild2>
    <taskChild3>Текст3</taskChild3>
</taskParent>
```

Далее вызываем метод `main()`:

```
public class Class2 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Class1 xml = new Class1();
        xml.initFileXML();//законнектимся к FILE_NAME

        //Добавим узлы
        ...
        ТекстA
        ...
        ТекстB
        ...
        ТекстD
        ...

        //и сразу же их считываем
        xml.readXML();

        //запишем изменения 
        xml.writeFileXML();

    }
}
```

и получаем вот такой xml-файл с добавленными узлами `ТекстA`, `ТекстB`, `ТекстD`:

```
<taskParent>
    <taskChild1>Текст1</taskChild1>
    <taskChild2>Текст2</taskChild2>
    <taskChild3>Текст3</taskChild3>
</taskParent>
<taskParent>
    <taskChild1>ТекстA</taskChild1>
    <taskChild2>ТекстB</taskChild2>
    <taskChild3>ТекстD</taskChild3>
</taskParent>
```

После вывода в консоль видим следующее:

```
Текст1
Текст2
Текст3

ТекстAТекстBТекстD
```

Должно было быть вот так:

```
ТекстA
ТекстB
ТекстD
```

А оно отображает в одну строчку:

```
ТекстAТекстBТекстD
```

Как нормализовать тот текст, который только что добавил?

И еще:
Если заново выполнить файл или в методе `main()` после вызова метода `xml.addNodeXML()` вставить эти методы: `writeFileXML();` `xml.initFileXML()`,
то информация из файла выводится  уже вот так:

```
Текст1
Текст2
Текст3

ТекстA
ТекстB
ТекстD , т.е. как и нужно
```

Другие способы решения предлагать не нужно. Для чего нужен метод `normalize()` объяснять не нужно. Мне нужно понять как работает нормализация `normalize()`.
Нигде внятной справки не нашел. На сайте oracle тоже ничего внятного нет.

Пытался посреди кода влепить `doc.normalize()`, но ничего не поменялось. Такое ощущение, что нормализация работает  один раз и только при запуске программы.

Comment: ну если же Вам сайт не подходят тогда идите и смотрите код этого метода. Это самый верный путь - что бы понять зачем нужен метод идут смотреть его код. Еще могут быть комментарии к методу от разработчиков.

Comment: @Tsyklop  - Попробую в коде разобраться. Если разберусь - выложу ответ.